# DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I'm trying to get simple DatePickerDialog working code bellow as can be found in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerDialogExample extends Activity {
    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        updateDisplay();
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                        .append(mDay).append("-")
                        .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                        mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

However I'm running into weird error

```
02-09 15:37:26.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:205)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
        at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:886)
        at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2557)
        at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524)
        at uk.co.peterscrorner.DatePickerDialogExample$1.onClick(DatePickerDialogExample.java:33)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
        ... 27 more
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/ic_dialog_info.png from drawable resource ID #0x108009b
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:118)
        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:108)
        ... 30 more
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/ic_dialog_info.png
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
        ... 33 more
```

Comment: I find this weird. Above code will run fine on HTC Desire HD with 2.3.3 but it will fail on button click in emulator with 2.3.3
Could be that there is some problem introduced in this week release of ADK r17?

Comment: Clean the project and try again

Comment: Done by default on every build since I use Maven setup

Answer (score 9):

In XML add a TextView and a Button

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search" />
```

Add following code in java file

```
public class DatePickerDialogExample extends Activity {

    TextView txtDate;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(PrayTimeActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // Display Selected date in textbox
                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: Now this `DatePickerDialog` sets date even when you click on back button what should not be happen.

Answer (score 1):

PS:Starts the day, month and year variables before the setOnClickListener should solve your problem.

OR

Try this simple Package:

```
public class DialogSelectDate extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Desenvolvido por Eduardo Ferreira
     * Simple DialogBox to DatePicker
     * @param _context
     * @param fromDateEtxt
     * @param dateFormatter
     */
    static void DialogDate(Context _context , final EditText fromDateEtxt , final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter) {
        fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth);
                fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }
        } , newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) , newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) , newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fromDatePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Call in you project

```
        EditText ed_edittext = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(`dd-MM-yyyy`, locale.US);

        DialogSelectDate.DialogDate(this, ed_edittext, dateFormatter );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this , you can set max date min date and also format the date

```
fun showDatePicker(context: Context, maximumDate: Long? = null, minimumDate: Long? = null, dateFormat: String = "dd/MM/yyyy",callBack: (String) -> Unit) {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    val dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, _year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, _year)
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US)
        callBack(sdf.format(c.time))
    }
    val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(context, dateSetListener, year, month, day)

    if (minimumDate != null) {
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate = minimumDate
    }
    if (maximumDate != null) {
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = maximumDate
    }
    datePickerDialog.show()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date Picker Dialog in Android Kotlin: - In This Dialog you can set min and max Date: -
```

val dp = fromDatePickerDialog.datePicker
dp.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis()

```
fun getDateDialog(textView: TextView, sActivity: Activity?): DatePickerDialog? {
            val fromDatePickerDialog: DatePickerDialog
            val newCalendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US)
            fromDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
                sActivity!!,
                { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                    val newDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
                    textView.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()))
                },
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            )
            val dp = fromDatePickerDialog.datePicker
            dp.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
            fromDatePickerDialog.show()
            return fromDatePickerDialog
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple example that demonstrates how to use DatePickerDialog:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Do something here
    }
}, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```